# Cannot connect to local dynamodb database

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

My app needs access to a dynamo db table and in order to simplify our development I created a local spring profile to use a local dynamo db instance.

To get things started I downloaded the latest version of local dynamo db from here [AWS developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html), unzipped the pack and started dynamo db with the command below:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /c/dev/DynamoDb/

Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: C:/dev/DynamoDb/
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

Trying to start again from another command prompt window will fail with port 8000 already in use.
This makes me think that all seemed to be started fine.

Now as a second step I created a dynamo db bean in my configuration class:

```
@Bean
@Profile("devlocal")
public AmazonDynamoDB localAmazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000/", "NoRegion"))
            .withCredentials(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("FakeAmazonAWSAccessKey", "FakeamazonAWSSecretKey")))
            .build();
}
```

This seems pretty basic setup. However when starting my application I am getting this exception in the logs and the app fails o start:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:397) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3899) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3794) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2797) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:250) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:263) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:336) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:142) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:78) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.java:31) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:36) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.resolveClientConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.java:169) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.access$000(AwsClientBuilder.java:54) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder$SyncBuilderParams.<init>(AwsClientBuilder.java:505) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getSyncClientParams(AwsClientBuilder.java:441) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.662.jar:na]
at com.my.company.my.app.webservice.config.DynamoConfig.localAmazonDynamoDB(DynamoConfig.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
```

Stopping the local dynamo db server ad retrying to start the application will produce exactly the same result which makes me think that the way in which I am trying to connect to the dynamo server in my code is not the proper way.

My local environment is windows 10.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

**NOTE**

I made exactly the same setup on my personal laptop and everything just worked fine. My laptop is running Fedora Linux but I don't think this should be the issue.

Comment: Provide the `aws-sdk` version and `DynamoConfig.java` line 55.

Comment: aws-java-sdk-dynamodb version is 1.11.662. The line 55 in the DynamoConfig.java is just the call to the build() method. If I evaluate the expression without the build() in debugger al resolves to a AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder instance

Comment: it seems like an issue of comflicting dependencies, if you are using maven see the dependency tree and check, where the dependencies for com.fasterxml.jackson.databind. are getting conflicted.

Comment: Yes best wishes that was the reason. I was restricted to use 1.11.662 as this was the latest one available on our company repository. I think this is buggy and it never worked as it depends on jackson-dataformat-cbor version 2.6.7. As soon as I forced to depend on 2.9.9 the problem went away. The aws-sdk was released at least 20 times this month only and not surprise dependency issues can slip in. Please publish your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Ta